# In C, is it ever O.K. to increment an uninitialized int?

Tags: c, initialization

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13666975/1830334), incrementing an uninitialized `int` in C results in undefined behavior. But what if I don't care at all about the initial value; for example, what if I just want an incrementing id? Is this *dangerous* or *bad practice* for any reason?

Comment: ehmm? YES, if it is UB everything can happen and it is dangerous and it's not even a practice at all (it's just horrible) **Your compiler should yell at you! And tell you NOT to do that**

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, which means that anything could happen.  That means the program could wipe your disk, or anything (the classic expression is 'make demons fly out of your nose' — search for 'nasal demons').  Why would you be against initializing the variable?

Comment: I'm not against initializing the variable, just curious because I've seen this done in what I consider nontrivial code.

Comment: If you don't care about actual value (which you don't know since value is undefined) - why do you want to increment it?

Comment: @gwg: Undefined **behavior** and undefined **value** are not the same thing

Comment: "*I've seen this done in what I consider nontrivial code*" -- from which we may infer that nontrivial code has bugs.

Comment: @KeithThompson, great point; just explaining the question. I didn't expect the amount of bolded text.

Comment: Believe the answer to this question would be quite different if it was "ever O.K. to increment an uninitialized `unsigned char`?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When most people read "this results in undefined behavior" they initially interpret it as "the value of your-variable-of-interest is indeterminate".

### This is wrong.

The text means literally what it means: the **behavior** of the *program itself* is undefined.
If they wanted to tell you that a value would be indeterminate, then they would say the value would be indeterminate. But they didn't. These are different sentences with different meanings.

When the **behavior** is undefined, it means the *program* is **meaningless** -- for example, the variable may no longer even *exist* at the point at which you make an inference about its value.
The program may not even be executing the code you think it is. It might just jump somewhere else, it might suddenly delete a file on your disk, it could do anything. Questioning the value of the variable is completely missing the point.

This is **just as bad** as your example, because while you might expect it to be equivalent to `i = 0`, it *also* results in undefined behavior:

```
int i;
i -= i;
```

i.e., undefined behavior has nothing to do with the value of any particular variable. It's about **behavior** (verb), not *data* (noun).

Comment: `When the behavior is undefined, it means the program is meaningless ` Yes using uninitilized variables leads to programs which doesn;t make any sense

Comment: @Gopi: Yes, that's correct, that's exactly what I'm saying, and that's also *not* the same thing as what you said in your own answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I was going to ask you to detail this in the comments. It seems that the root of my question was a misunderstanding of what "undefined behavior" really was. It's not simply that an incremented, undefined `int` can hold any unexpected value—and the host of issues that that can present—but rather that that code is vacuous, rendering the whole program meaningless as well.

Comment: @gwg: Yes, exactly. Now you got it :)

Comment: @gwg: If it piques your interest, look up "trap representations". I'll summarize it for you: a trap representation is a value that can result in the CPU "trapping" (e.g. crashing the program). The fact that `i` could be stored in a register that has a trap representation and the fact that you haven't explicitly initialized it to a non-trapping value means that simply *reading* it can crash the program. So even `int i; printf("%d", i);` results in undefined behavior. Make sure you've understood this.

Answer (score 8):

If the value of an object with *automatic storage duration* is accessed, and the object is uninitialized, the behavior is  undefined. This is explicitly and formally stated in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.2.1 paragraph 2 (that's the latest public draft of the ISO C standard).

"*Undefined behavior*" doesn't just mean that you might get any arbitrary value. It means "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements" ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 3.4.3). The language standard says literally nothing about what accessing such an object's value means. It's effectively pure gibberish. (The standard joke is that undefined behavior can cause demons to fly out of your nose. Of course in real life it can't -- but if it did you couldn't complain that the compiler is non-conforming.)

But let's ignore for a moment the undefined behavior of accessing an uninitialized `int`. Maybe you're feeling lucky today. Maybe you know how your compiler will handle this case.

More precisely, let's make some plausible assumptions about how that undefined behavior can manifest.

Suppose we have:

```
int i;
i ++;
```

Suppose the (undefined) initial value of `i` happens to be `INT_MAX`. Then incrementing `i` causes a signed integer overflow, which again is explicitly undefined behavior ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5 paragraph 5). Even if the initial value is less than `INT_MAX`, incrementing it enough times will cause an overflow -- and since you don't know what the initial value is, you don't know how many times you can "safely" increment it.

The most likely bad consequence is that an optimizing compiler will transform the code in ways that depend on the *assumption* that its behavior is defined. Here's an example not involving an uninitialized variable:

```
int i = INT_MAX;
int j = i + 1;
if (j > i) { /* ... */ }
```

If addition obeys the common wraparound 2's-complement semantics (which are *not* guaranteed by the C standard, but are commonly what's implemented in hardware), then `j` will be equal to `INT_MIN`, and `(j > i)` will be false. Logically, `(j > i)` *must* be false, because no `int` value can exceed `INT_MAX`. But since `j` was set to `i + 1`, then `(j > i)` *must* be true (for any program that has defined behavior).

Whatever your expectations might be for the behavior of this code, an optimizing compiler may legally violate them. If you're lucky, it might warn you before breaking your code, but it's not required to.

You'll spend far less time adding an `= 0` to the declaration of `i` than we've spent discussing what happens if you don't. (But even then, you might run into problems if you increment `i` enough times to cause an overflow.)

Comment: For information, this was a number overflow in the autopilot code...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp_D8r-2hwk

Answer (score 2):

While the "Undefined Behavior" is very likely to be an undefined value in the variable in no way should you write code that would make that assumption.

Some of the other posters are making the point of undefined behavior by giving an extreme example of deleting your home directory.  We all know that the example is extreme, but the point they are making is not extreme.

A realistic future "Undefined Behavior" could be a segmentation fault triggered by enhanced memory fault checking.

Memory fault checking as performed by debugging tools such as "Purify" can detect these type of bugs.  It is not completely far fetched to consider that these type of tools might evolve to have low enough overhead that they would be used in production code to trap such "Undefined Behavior".

That is, for some future implementations, the "Undefined Behavior" would be a segmentation fault.